# C# - Simplify ValueType cast

Tags: c#

So i have question, is there any way to simplify this cast ?

```
(TabControl.SelectedTab.Tag as (CodeFile codeFile, TreeNode node)?).Value
```

The ValueType is gonna always have a value, so is there a way to get rid of the `.Value` ?

Comment: Lesson of the day: don't abuse tuples.

Comment: Why are you doing this cast in the first place?

Comment: @Sweeper; We discovered that the var keyword does not understand tuples, not that tuples were abused. Keep your design decisions to yourself ;)

Comment: @Watachiaieto Those not personal design decisions, but good practices.

Comment: With one line of code, there is no way you can tell what is or isn't good design practice. In c++11, it is encouraged to use tuples over structures in some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before as, there was this "null" pattern that was always used.

```
if ({thing is a thingy}) {
    thingy newThing = (thingy)thing;
    /*Code stuff here*/
}
```

the problem was that people found that sometimes inbetween casting the type could change etc etc...

So they gave the "as" operator - which does a cast and returns the variable as a thingy immediatly, or a null otherwise and a it prevents the null pointer problem.

You don't actually need the as operator in this case if you know that the type is certain and that the object won't be null. if That is the case, just do the regular cast pattern.

```
(object)TabControl.SelectedTab.Tag
```

(I am not certain if this is right - since I have never seen an object casted to something that almost looks like a function :P

```
(CodeFile codeFile, TreeNode node) result = (CodeFile codeFile, TreeNode node)TabControl.SelectedTab.Tag
```

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I think I already tried the second cast you suggested and it threw an error

Comment: Give me a short section of compileable code and I can do some fiddling.
I have never worked with tuples, so I don't know exactly what I'm doing - just speculating that the "as" operator is not what you want in this situation ;)

Comment: I think casting it to type "object" is enough and c# figures out it is a tuple. Worked for me in the watch window...

Comment: Wait. Wrong again. I think I have it now though ;)

Comment: I think the compiler gets confused as the "var" keyword may not fully understand what it is receiving, so the tuple format looks like a call to a function that was not named. Putting the type in front of the new object pointer gives the compiler a much stronger clue as to whats happening XD

Comment: Also, fixed in the example ;)
https://hastebin.com/safelagini.cs

Answer (score 1):

First: this is bad code, because in case of unsuccessfull cast, `as` returns `null`, so in such case you will get `NullReferenceException`.

Second: you cast to a `Tuple`, this type doesn't have property named `Value`

Third: `?` operator should be used right before dot: `...?.Value`

To answer your question: in order to access any property on a object, we need to "ask for it" by writing its name, so no, you can't omit `Value` here if you want to access it.

So, your code should look like this:

```
(TabControl.SelectedTab.Tag as (CodeFile codeFile, TreeNode node))?.Item1 // or it could be Item2
```

Comment: The OP specifically stated that it would always have a value, so there is no need to check for nulls.
How/Why are you giving opinions on their coding style as you look at LITERALLY one line of their code?

Comment: @Watachiaieto I giving opinions bout that particular line of code..